# 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable how to determine if app or not

Tags: openshift

How do I determine if this

> '503 Service Temporarily Unavailable'

message is caused by my app having a problem running, or something else?

Should I assume that it's my app not being able to restart?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to determing this is to access the logs: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-log-files.html

```
$ rhc tail -a $APP_NAME
# or
$ rhc ssh -a $APP_NAME
$ cat app-root/logs/*.log
```